# Java "Loop" Program?

Tags: java, terminal, command-prompt

It's been a while since I've done some Java coding but here is a simple program, I did to calculate markup for my retail store. How would I be able to make the program loop until I close it myself? Right now, I run this program in my terminal/command prompt and each time I enter a value it ends, so I am forced to execute it again which takes some time (about .05 seconds or less) however I need all the time I can get with this task I am doing. So the point is to keep it running until I close it myself.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProductMarkup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        out.print("What is the quantity?");
        int quantity = myScanner.nextInt();
        out.print("What is the wholesale price?");
        double wsprice = myScanner.nextDouble();


        if (quantity == 1) {
            double math = (int) (wsprice * .70);
            double retail = math + wsprice;
            out.println(retail + 5);
        } else if (quantity == 2) {
            double math = wsprice * 2;
            double retail = math + 10;
            out.println(retail);
        } else if (quantity == 3) {
            double math = wsprice * 2.5;
            double retail = math + 5.75;
            out.println(retail);
        } else if (quantity == 4) {
            double math = wsprice * 2.80;
            double retail = math + 3.75;
            out.println(retail);
        }
       }

    }
```

Comment: `while (true) { /* looped code here */ }`

Comment: Thank you. I totally forgot about while loops..

Comment: [The while and do-while Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) and [The for Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, You can use one of the following three loops:

1. while Loop

A while loop is a control structure that allows you to repeat a task a certain number of times.

Syntax:
The syntax of a while loop is:

```
while(Boolean_expression)
{
   //Statements
}
```

> **When executing, if the boolean_expression result is true**, then the actions inside the loop will be executed. This will continue as long
>   as the expression result is true.

2. do...while Loop

Syntax:
The syntax of a do...while loop is:

```
do
{
   //Statements
}while(Boolean_expression);
```

> Notice that the Boolean expression appears at the end of the loop, so
>   the statements in the loop execute once before the Boolean is tested.
>
> **If the Boolean expression is true, the flow of control jumps back up to do, and the statements in the loop execute again.** This process
>   repeats until the Boolean expression is false.

3. for Loop

> A for loop is a repetition control structure that allows you to
>   efficiently write a loop that needs to execute a specific number of
>   times.
>
> A for loop is useful when you know how many times a task is to be
>   repeated.

Syntax:
The syntax of a for loop is:

```
for(initialization; Boolean_expression; update)
{
   //Statements
}
```

In the for loop case, you can use as follows if you want to repeat your processes for ever.

```
for(;;){
   whatever process you have
}
```

Hope from what I provide you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Phylogenesis said, you can literally just wrap your code in a `while(true)`. However, if you want to ask if the program should be restarted, use something along the lines of

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean running = true;
while(running)
{
    // your program code here
    System.out.print("restart? ");
    running = myScanner.nextLine().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a while loop with a sentinel value to continuously get inputs. For this example when you're done enter -1 to exit.

```
public class ProductMarkup {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);


    out.print("What is the quantity?");
    int quantity = myScanner.nextInt();
    out.print("What is the wholesale price?");
    double wsprice = myScanner.nextDouble();
    //while loop here
    while(quantity != -1){

    if (quantity == 1) {
        double math = (int) (wsprice * .70);
        double retail = math + wsprice;
        out.println(retail + 5);
    } else if (quantity == 2) {
        double math = wsprice * 2;
        double retail = math + 10;
        out.println(retail);
    } else if (quantity == 3) {
        double math = wsprice * 2.5;
        double retail = math + 5.75;
        out.println(retail);
    } else if (quantity == 4) {
        double math = wsprice * 2.80;
        double retail = math + 3.75;
        out.println(retail);

    out.print("What is the quantity?");
    int quantity = myScanner.nextInt();
    out.print("What is the wholesale price?");
    double wsprice = myScanner.nextDouble();

    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProductMarkup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int quantity;
        do {
            out.print("What is the quantity?");
            quantity = myScanner.nextInt();
            out.print("What is the wholesale price?");
            double wsprice = myScanner.nextDouble();


            if (quantity == 1) {
                double math = (int) (wsprice * .70);
                double retail = math + wsprice;
                out.println(retail + 5);
            } else if (quantity == 2) {
                double math = wsprice * 2;
                double retail = math + 10;
                out.println(retail);
            } else if (quantity == 3) {
                double math = wsprice * 2.5;
                double retail = math + 5.75;
                out.println(retail);
            } else if (quantity == 4) {
                double math = wsprice * 2.80;
                double retail = math + 3.75;
                out.println(retail);
            }
        } while (quantity != -1);
    }
}
```